# Having an issue converting a set of very large integers into timedeltas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with a dataframe that includes a column of integers where the units are the number of days since 0001-01-01. I need to convert these integers into current dates. When I attempt use the pd.to_timedelta function to convert these integers into TimeDeltas that I can then add to the start date, the resulting time deltas do not result in what I expect. Please run the following code for an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([735110,735111,735112,735114], columns=["days_since_0001-01-01"])
df['time_added'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['days_since_0001-01-01'], unit='d')
print(df[0:1])
#output: 735110 94598 days 01:16:18.871345152
```

As you can see, the timedelta result for the first row in days is 94,598, plus additional units for the hours/seconds/minutes etc. What I was expecting for that row was 735,110 days, plus 0s for the rest of the timestamp. Further, if I use a DataFrame with a smaller number of days, the output is as I would expect. I have come to the conclusion that to_timedelta cannot handle very large numbers of days; however, I do not know of an alternative method to do this. I could simply reduce the number of days by an arbitrary amount and increase the start date, but I would still need to know the proper amount by which to reduce the days integer and the amount by which to increase the start date. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Confirming your conclusion: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html#timedelta-limitations Also perhaps relevant: the `Timestamp` limits: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations

Comment: I think I figured it out. Every year is 365 days, except for leap years which are 366 days. So I just need to pick an arbitrary point within the acceptable timedelta resolutions, (e.x. 1850), calculate the number of regular years and leap years between 0000-01-01 and 1850-01-01, multiply regular by 365 and leap by 366, then subtract that from my days_since_0001-01-01. Then I can set a start date as 1850-01-01, and add the remaining amount of days to that start date, to get the current date.

Comment: what exactly is your desired result data type? (in the heading you write about timedelta, in the comment "... to get the current date")

Comment: Hello Stef, I'm working with multiple datasets, each of which has a time column in # of days since XXXX-XX-XX days, where the starting date is not the same. I am using the time column to index them to make the data comparable, and then run time series analysis on each of the different data sets for comparison.  I ultimately will be working with date over # of days since a given date, as that will be simpler to explain to the eventual end-users of my research. That said, I have resolved this matter using the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Every year is 365 days, except for leap years which are 366 days and occur every four years. So I just need to pick an arbitrary point within the acceptable timedelta resolutions, (e.x. 1850), calculate the number of regular years and leap years between 0000-01-01 and 1850-01-01, multiply regular by 365 and leap by 366, then subtract that from my days_since_0001-01-01. Then I can set a start date as 1850-01-01, and add the remaining amount of days to that start date, to get the current date.